# Is it possible to use both Blender Render and Cycles in one render?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

If I wanted to use cycles for a (example) floor and blender render for a (example) humanoid figure, how would I go about doing it? Is there a non complicated way to combine both cycles and blender render in one render output?
Thanks!

Comment: Use different scenes, one for Cycles, another for Internal and composite render layers.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know you could do that. You can submit that as an answer, it is one after all. Thanks again!